# Custom post type – customise single.php in child theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I’ve managed to create my first custom post type (in this case artists) but I want to customise how the single page layout look when click on ‘Read more’ about the artist? So far, I have copied the single.php from the Kalium theme to Kalium child theme, but do not know how to change the code in single.php

The page I need help with:
https://staging2.africanwomensplaywrightnetwork.org/artist/philisiwe-twijnstra/

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: AWPN Featured Article
* Template Post Type: Artists
*/
/**
* Kalium WordPress Theme
*
* Single post template.
*
* @author Laborator
* @link https://kaliumtheme.com
*/
if ( ! defined( ‘ABSPATH’ ) ) {
exit; // Direct access not allowed.
}

/**
* Theme header.
*/
get_header();

/**
* Show post information if exists.
*/
if ( have_posts() ) :

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

/**
* kalium_blog_single_before_content
*
* @hooked kalium_blog_single_post_image_full_width – 10
**/
do_action( ‘kalium_blog_single_before_content’ );

?>
<div <?php kalium_blog_single_container_class(); ?>>

<div class=”container”>

<div class=”row”>

<?php
/**
* kalium_blog_single_content hook
*
* @hooked kalium_blog_single_post_image_boxed – 10
* @hooked kalium_blog_single_post_layout – 20
* @hooked kalium_blog_single_post_sidebar – 30
**/
do_action( ‘kalium_blog_single_content’ );
?>

</div>

</div>

</div>
<?php

/**
* kalium_blog_single_after_content
*
* @hooked kalium_blog_single_post_comments – 10
**/
do_action( ‘kalium_blog_single_after_content’ );

endwhile;

endif;

/**
* Theme footer.
*/
get_footer();
```

Comment: That theme appears to use a lot of hooks to actually create the output - so you will either have to add your own functions to those hooks (and probably remove the existing ones); or you overwrite what's inside the loop there with your own custom code that generates the output you desire directly.

Comment: P.s., if you make changes to the single.php in your child theme, that will apply to the single display of _all_ post types. If you don't want that, then create a template specifically for your custom type, https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you give `Template Name: AWPN Featured Article` a new unique name.

Then go inside an artist's post and select from the right sidebar the new Template you created.

Write some content, publish, and check the page in the front-end.